# How to disable *Python Completions*?

Tags: python, completion

When I work on a `.py` file a new buffer appear (`*Python Completions*`) and sometimes auto-complete my code (every time in a wrong way !).

It looks like this (on the right side, when I tiped `i`):

[image]

What is causing it and how may I disable it ?

Comment: Does this happen when you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If not then recursively bisect your init file to find out what you are doing that causes it.

Comment: @Drew I finally found with your method. The `jedi` package was installed in my load-dir and I use `company`, thus both interacted in a wrong way! The sollution just was to remove the `jedi` package. Thanks you for your help.

Comment: This also happens when you have python-mode.el installed. It may also be a conflict with company

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem came from the interaction between `jedi` and `company`. Both interact in a wrong way, as it is explained [here](https://github.com/syohex/emacs-company-jedi#installation), so company users must install `company-jedi` instead of `jedi`.

Thus the solution was just to remove the `jedi` package!